# How do I fix android's recycler view rendering issue which only displays single rows

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I recently started getting this issue on an app I am working on android. It suddenly started rendering single rows on the page. A new row gets displayed only as the previous row scrolls out of the screen.[Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHJno.png) Any help is appreciated.

Comment: paste xml here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add wrap_content to the layout height to the parent layout that holds cardview. it will solve the problem. here is some snippet that will help you.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/quote_card"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#666"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

   //other views here


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I'm not sure why it worked before when I had height as match_parent.